# Did US AG Jeff Sessions violate his promise to recuse himself from the Trump/Russia probe?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, fbi

After it was discovered that Sessions had lied to the Senate during his confirmation hearing about contacts with Russia, he back-filled by saying he'd recuse himself from any involvement with investigations into links between the Trump Administration or the Trump Presidential Campaign, and Russia.

[NY Times: Sessions Recuses Himself From Russia Probe](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/02/us/politics/jeff-sessions-russia-trump-investigation-democrats.html)

It has been reported, by the Trump White House, that the firing of FBI Director, James Comey, whose FBI was investigating the allegations of Russian meddling, along with claims of links to the Trump Administration and campaign, was at the recommendation of Deputy AG Rosenstein, along with AG Jeff Sessions, who approved, passed along and concurred with the recommendation.

[NY Times: FBI Director James Comey Fired By Trump](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/09/us/politics/james-comey-fired-fbi.html)

Since he just recommended removal the person in charge of an investigation that he promised to recuse himself from, did Sessions violate his pledge to not get involved?

If so, what, if any consequences are there, short-term (I suspect "none") are there for violating that promise?

Comment: I think this is very close to  “______ sucks, am I right?" And have voted to close.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - It's not the intent, but you're certainly entitled to exercise your down or close votes as you see fit. My impression was "how is this not the case?"  But I have an opinion/perspective on it, that might be blinding me to possibilities, so I ask for others to give their input.  I'm actually more interested in well-constructed contrary answers than affirming ones for this.

Comment: Input, opinions, perspective, etc. aren't copacetic with the SE Model.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - Input certainly is.  That's what asking a question and getting an answer is all about.  That's what Q&A is.  I'm not asking for an opinion for opinion's sake, or for another opinion, at all. I'm asking for input because I think my own opinions might be skewing my perspective, so I'm asking for, as I said, "well-constructed answers" to I might get past any sort of bias from my opinions. This seems to be **exactly** in line with the SE model.  I'm not sure why you think otherwise.

Comment: If Sessions were not directly impacting the investigation, the details of how the firing rolled out, the processes or mechanisms used to isolate him from anything but a required perfunctory role could be laid out, objectively.  I'm not asking if Sessions was right or wrong to do so, I'm asking if his role was an active one.  Not sure why that's seemingly more "opinion-based" than just about any question on this stack.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Whether or not it's "active", or constitutes any meaningful violation of his self-recusal (and if such a thing is even possible: if recusal is generally optional and self-imposed, in what sense does it create a legal obligation that isn't entirely self-dictated?), sounds like a legal debate. I'm not sure there's anything specifically political about it, other than the usual politicization of legal terminology.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy it's not a legal question from what I see. That said, it's going to be primarily opinion based. I do believe that, given Sessions actions, clearly he's being completely disingenuous. But this is heavily partisan politics and, at least for now, there are clearly people in congress that have the opposite opinion. We simply don't know what the consequences are until things unfold over the next few weeks. I'm getting the popcorn ready.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - If Sessions had, for instance, said something like "Since I promised to recuse myself, I had a panel of deputies who vetted any recommendations and I agreed to pass their recommendations on without editing or deciding whether or not they should be moved forward" - opinion about that or not, that would be a process that I was not aware of.  Now, maybe everyone thinks it's entirely opinion based because there's nothing that we're missing. *That's* what I'm really looking for - information that I'm not aware of, or, confirmation that I'm not missing any pieces.

Comment: One does not need legal expertise or specific understanding to share something like that.

Comment: It's a 100% legitimate and interesting question that could be phrased a bit more neutrally. Perhaps more appropriate to law.stackexchange

Comment: Violate what? Is there a law that makes his promise legally binding, is there a differentiating line between what is interference and what isn't? Sounds like a primary opinion based question. For that reason, I've voted to close it; since it has been re-opened, and I can't vote to close it again.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - "Violate what?"  Wording of the question - "Violate his pledge."  Is there something about that wording that makes it mysterious to you?  I understand you don't care for the question.  If you have a problem with how close-question votes work, that has nothing to do with me.  If you want a legal issue, lying to Congress while under oath is actually illegal.

Comment: http://blogs.findlaw.com/blotter/2017/03/what-are-the-penalties-for-lying-to-congress.html

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Did he lie under oath? When Al Franken asked: "But if it's true, it's obviously extremely serious and if there is any evidence that anyone affiliated with the Trump campaign communicated with the Russian government in the course of this campaign, what will you do?" and Sessions answered "Senator Franken, I'm not aware of any of those activities. I have been called a surrogate at a time or two in that campaign and I didn't have — did not have communications with the Russians, and I'm unable to comment on it." Did that mean he did not communicate with Russians as a Trump Surrogate?

Comment: @DrunkCynic - He's not saying "I did not have communcations with the Russians in that capacity, as part of the Trump campaign," he's saying "I did not have communications with the Russians."  There's no qualifier involved here.  And if he told Congress that he would completely recuse himself from the investigation, and violated that pledge, that would make his promise a lie, as well.  I only mentioned that since you seemed very agitated by the word "violate" and seemed to insist that it must have some kind of legal connotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An AP reporter recently asked [this exact question](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/rundown/sessions-break-recusal-vow-helping-fire-comey/) in a brief article. As she states, "the answer partly depends on what you see as the real motive behind the director’s firing."

Sen. Al Franken is a prominent example of someone who sees a contradiction. As [quoted on The Hill](http://thehill.com/homenews/administration/332671-dem-senator-sessions-recommendation-to-fire-comey-a-complete-betrayal):

> “I am also deeply troubled by the fact that Attorney General Jeff
> Sessions, who pledged to recuse himself from the Russia investigation
> because of his own Russia connections, involved himself in Director
> Comey’s firing,” Franken said in a statement. “**This is a complete
> betrayal of his commitment** to the public that he wouldn’t be involved
> in the investigation.”

Also Sen. Ron Wyden, as quoted [on Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/jeff-sessions-james-comey_us_591318d5e4b05e1ca2038fec):

> “I urge people to compare the statement that the attorney general made
> with respect to recusal to the events of the last day or so, with the
> president of the United States specifically mentioning in connection
> with those letters, the investigation of Russia. I think it showed **a
> blatant disregard for the commitment to recuse himself**,” Wyden said.

HuffPo further quotes a legal scholar who thinks there is a legitimate case here:

> Stephen Gillers, a New York University School of Law professor
> specializing in legal ethics, said **Sessions “reneged on his recusal**
> promise to the Senate,” pointing to Sessions’ statement from March: “I
> have decided to recuse myself from any existing or future
> investigations of any matters related in any way to the campaigns for
> President of the United States.”
>
> “That’s ‘campaigns’ plural,” Gillers said. “**The grounds for firing Mr.
> Comey** in the Rosenstein memorandum are explicitly stated to be Mr.
> Comey’s public comments about Mrs. Clinton during the campaigns. These
> grounds **are plainly encompassed within Mr. Sessions’ description of
> the broad scope of his recusal.**”

But the AP piece includes a dissenting opinion:

> Sessions recommended Comey’s firing, writing in a letter that “a fresh
> start is needed at the leadership of the FBI.” And President Donald
> Trump said he based the firing on Comey’s very public handling of the
> bureau’s investigation into Clinton’s emails.
>
> In that context, the move can be seen as **purely a personnel decision based on
> Comey’s conduct**, and Sessions should have been involved given his job as
> attorney general, said Susan Hennessey, a fellow at the Brookings
> Institution and managing editor of the Lawfare blog.
>
> [...]
>
> There’s **no legal penalty** for Sessions if he should have stayed out of the firing, **though Congress could grill him** over it or seek an inspector general investigation, Hennessey said.

Comment: Good stuff.  Look forward to seeing if others come up with anything else.  It will be interesting if Trump's statements that he really didn't do this on the recommendation of anyone - that had already decided he was firing Comey, regardless, creates a "shield" of sorts.